# What do you call a person who does a very special and rare job?

Tags: vocabulary

I am looking for a perfect and general word describing a person who does a very special, uncommon and rare job. For example, what is the best word describing a veteran miller who works in a traditional windmill? In fact, I am looking for something like "rare-job doer". Is there any proper word in English?

Comment: Presumably "specialist" doesn't convey the element of rarity that you require?

Comment: @KillingTime With everyone and his uncle doing a "specialist" and "superspecialist" job in his own domain, we needed help from "generalist" to save the day.

Comment: @KillingTime Let me add another example. Suppose there is a very old lighthouse and a man still works in it. His father and his grandfather also used to work in the lighthouse. So he continues his ancestor's job. This is called the "Intangible Cultural Heritage". Same as the veteran miller I mentioned, he does a rare job. "Specialist" is not a good word here. So what can we call those men?

Comment: Related - [Living Human Treasure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Living_Human_Treasure)

Comment: I doubt if there is a single word for it. You just have to say they "have a unique job" or similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **unconventional**
>
> different from what is usual or from the way most people do things:
>
> *unconventional profession*

Source: [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/unconventional)